# How to use "Merge by Distance" node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

There is a certain model duplicated by the "Instance on Points" node. They overlap perfectly, but for some reason the node "merge by distance" refuses to connect them. Am I doing something wrong?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your geometry is composed of duplicated instances.

Separate instances can't be merged together as they are equivalent to different objects.

To merge the ends together you must realize instances first with a *Instances > Realize Instances* node.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it weird that "Join Geometry" joins instances and geometry without warning?

Comment: No, join geometry does just that, joins it. It doesn't merge it nor fuse vertex together.

Comment: @arachnoden "Join Geometry" does the same thing as pressing Ctrl+J in the 3D view. It puts all the geometry from one object into the other, but doesn't do anything further with it, overlapping or not.